# Convert D3 array data from AJAX call with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've got a d3plus function that takes data in this format and I would like to replace it with an AJAX call that brings back JSON instead. I'm not sure how to "convert" the returned JSON into the equivalent of JavaScript array for compliance with D3/D3plus:

```
var data = [
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20000", "grade":82},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20001", "grade":42},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20002", "grade":55},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20003", "grade":62}
]
```

Comment: Is `data` the JSON that was returned or what you need for d3?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand what you want, but I understand that you need convert json to array javascript.

Then, you can use "for ... of" of ECMAScript6

```
var data = [
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20000", "grade":82},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20001", "grade":42},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20002", "grade":55},
{"course": "C1301_088", "studentid":"20003", "grade":62}
]
var course = [], studentid = [], grade = [];

for (let key of data){
    course.push(key.course);
    studentid.push(key.studentid);
    grade.push(key.grade);
}

console.log(course);
console.log(studentid);
console.log(grade)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PabloCordova/5u7gj27f/)